# How to choose between functions and objects

Tags: object-oriented, object-oriented-design, functions

I have seen different approaches and it is not clear to me which one is the correct one.

- Some developers use lots of small, very specific objects, and compose them in some way to achieve their goal.
- Other developers use objects as a collection of lots of methods and functions. In this case, an object takes care of a range of tasks linked to the same goal.

I can see downsides in both approaches:

- The first approach (in my opinion) reduces the sense of having tools as functions and methods.
- The second approach can become quite messy if the same class is responsible for too many tasks (I'm used to this approach and, probably, I can't see all of the other downsides).

Both approaches can lead to difficulties in readability and maintainability.

When comparing the pros and cons of both approaches, can either of them be recommended based on objective reasons?

Comment: Personally, I'm more of an OOP guy by experience.  But the best approach is to **follow what the rest of the code base generally uses**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First option is what object orientation is all about and has been raging for decades in many areas of software development for multiple reasons, especially for big projects with many programmers involved.

Not every programming language supports object orientation, though. But even so, separation of concerns is what makes it possible for a maintainer to be able to modify one part or the code without causing errors in non-related parts.

It comes a time when code gets so big that you cannot have the big picture in your mind at all times. Classes that do too much, God objects etc., force you to understand too many things in order to be brave enough to change something. In the other hand static classes with lots of utility methods are not so harmful, like for example the `Math` class in the Java SDK.

Your mileage may vary but object orientation when applied well leads to more components that have only one reason to change. It has led to patterns being recognized, named and standardized, the creation of frameworks that save time, etc.

Comment: +1 And not to speak about people who understand SRP the wrong way and create way too many classes, thinking the class should “do one thing” (which to the extreme could lead to one class, one method) instead of the class having “one reason to change” (which is the real intent of SRP and leads to a much more balanced and maintainable size for the classes)